# Script: Rotate objects around pivot of one of them

Tags: scripting

I‘m trying to rotate two objects A and B around the pivot point of A, with a specified target rotation (in a script). I got it working for a single axis, but not for all axis. The script below correctly rotates A but the rotation of B is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

```
### ALL AXIS

# Deselect all objects bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# Select Obj A
A.select_set(True)

# Select Obj B
B.select_set(True)

# Set A to be the active obj
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = A

# Calculate the rotation degrees
rotation_degrees = (142, 0, 0)  # X, Y, Z rotations

# Set the pivot point for rotation to be the origin of A
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center='BOUNDS')

# Rotate both objects around the pivot point of object A
pivot_location = A.location

# Convert to radians
rotation_radians = [math.radians(angle) for angle in rotation_degrees]

# Calculate the rotation around the pivot
A.rotation_euler = Euler(rotation_radians, 'XYZ')
rotation_matrix = Euler(rotation_radians, 'XYZ').to_matrix()
relative_position = B.location - pivot_location
rotated_relative_position = rotation_matrix @ relative_position

# Apply transforms to B
B.location = rotated_relative_position + pivot_location
B.rotation_euler = Euler(rotation_radians, 'XYZ')

# Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

My solution for rotating on a single axis (this works):

```
## ONE AXIS


# Deselect all objects bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# Select Obj A
A.select_set(True)

# Select Obj B
B.select_set(True)

# Set A to be the active obj
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = A

# Calculate the rotation degrees
rotation_degrees = 142

# Set the pivot point for rotation to be the origin of A
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center='BOUNDS')

# Set the pivot to A
pivot_location = A.location

# Convert to radians
rotation_radians = math.radians(rotation_degrees)

# Calculate the rotation around the pivot
A.rotation_euler.x += rotation_radians
B.location -= pivot_location
rotation_matrix = Euler((rotation_radians, 0, 0), 'XYZ').to_matrix()

# Apply transforms to B
B.location = rotation_matrix @ B.location
B.location += pivot_location
B.rotation_euler.x += rotation_radians

# Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! I'm not sure what you mean by 1 axis or all axes. Can you add a drawing or screenshot that illustrates the problem and what your expected result is? It's easier to visualize and help find solution.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thank you for the welcome :) I'm trying to match the rotation of the two objects to the rotation of another reference object (that is my target rotation represented in the rotation_degrees variable). That's why the rotation might need to happen on multiple axis; depending on how the referenced object is rotated. In my example, I'm just assuming the target rotation is 0 on all axis except for X, so I can only rotate on that single axis (and that works with the code I provided). If however, the reference object is rotated on more than one axis, I need to account for that.

Comment: Does that explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

Rotation is always around the origin (world origin for `matrix_world`), so in order to rotate around some pivot, you need to first shift the coordinate space so that the pivot is at the origin, and after the rotation you shift back:

```py
from bpy import data as D

A = D.objects['Pivot Cube']
B = D.objects['Rotated Cube']
empty = D.objects['Empty']

locA = A.matrix_world.translation
mat_rot = empty.rotation_euler.to_matrix().to_4x4()

B.matrix_world.translation -= locA         # 1) position pivot at world origin
B.matrix_world = mat_rot @ B.matrix_world  # 2) rotate
B.matrix_world.translation += locA         # 3) counter the translation from 1)
```

Below I first put some arbitrary Location on the *Parented Cube*, then rotate the empty parent of this cube, then I modify the Location of the *Parented Cube* further just to show the order of changing those doesn't matter, and then I reveal hidden *Rotated Cube* (it's only ABOUT to be rotated), and run the script to do the same thing without parenting by using matrix calculations. Oh and I also <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> copy and <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> paste the Location, because those have to match:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure I was able to exactly follow your explanation in regards to my issue (I'm trying to rotate both objects A+B around the pivot (= center) of A), but your explanation about rotations happening around the world origin gave me the idea to further look into that. Turns out my issue was, I had to apply the rotation after the translation using euler.rotate(). Corrected script in my answer below:

Comment: @gedankenpolaroid You can rotate the A object in exactly the same way you rotated the B object. Perhaps you need to modify `locA = A.matrix_world.translation` to `locA = A.matrix_world.translation.copy()`, and then `B = A` and that's it.

Comment: Thank you, I will see if I can make it work that way as well, might solve my other issue with scaling at the same time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. Here is my corrected script, including getting the rotation of my reference object (the rotation I want to apply to both A and B):

[image]

```
import bpy
import math
from mathutils import Euler

# Replace "A" with the actual name of your objects
A = bpy.data.objects["A"]
new_obj = bpy.data.objects["B"]

# Calculate the rotation difference matrix between A and the reference object for later use
rotation_difference_matrix = A.rotation_euler.to_matrix() @ ref_obj.rotation_euler.to_matrix().inverted()

# Match the rotation of A to ref_obj_selected so new_obj can be correctly positioned and be rotated with A later
A.rotation_euler = ref_obj.rotation_euler

# Check the difference in location between ref_obj_selected and A
offset_location_selected_to_linked = A.location - ref_obj_selected.location

# Position new_obj with the offset_location_selected_to_linked
new_obj.location += offset_location_selected_to_linked

# Handle rotation using context:
# 1. Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
# 2. Select new_obj
new_obj.select_set(True)
# 3. Select A
A.select_set(True)
# 4. Set A to be the active obj
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = A

# Convert rotation matrix to Euler angles
rotation_difference_euler = rotation_difference_matrix.to_euler('XYZ')

# Convert radians to degrees
rotation_degrees = [math.degrees(angle) for angle in rotation_difference_euler]

# Set the pivot point for rotation to be the origin of A
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center='BOUNDS')

# Get the pivot location
pivot_location = A.location

# Calculate the rotation matrix for each axis
rotation_matrix = Euler(rotation_difference_euler, 'XYZ').to_matrix()

# Rotate both objects around the pivot point of A
for obj in [A, new_obj]:
    # Calculate the relative position of the object from the pivot point
    relative_position = obj.location - pivot_location

    # Rotate the object
    obj.rotation_euler.rotate(rotation_matrix)

    # Apply the rotated position back to the object
    obj.location = pivot_location + rotation_matrix @ relative_position

# Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDmbH.gif
```