# Matrix.Rotation for all axis? (Script)

Tags: scripting

I'm writing a script to match the location, rotation and scale of two objects A+B to a reference object, by using the pivot point (origin) of A to rotate / scale around.

*(This is a follow-up to my previous question: [Script: Rotate objects around pivot of one of them](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/300171/173011) - I've found the below solution works better for also matching the scale, but results in the following new issue. Hence the new question.)*

I'm having trouble getting the correct syntax for rotating around all of the axis. Here is the main part I'm having trouble with:

```
# Rotate & scale both objects around the pivot point of A
for obj in [A, B]:
    M = (
        Matrix.Translation(pivot_location) @
        Matrix.Diagonal((scale_factor_x, scale_factor_y, scale_factor_z)).to_4x4() @
        Matrix.Rotation(rotation_angle_x, 4, (1, 0, 0)) @      
        Matrix.Translation(-pivot_location)
        )
    obj.matrix_world = M @ obj.matrix_world
```

Rotation for one axis works with this code (using the X axis here).
But how can I adjust this to also adjust rotation for Y and Z?
Can I replace `Matrix.Rotation(rotation_angle_x, 4, (1, 0, 0)) @`  with anything that handles the rotation for all axis? I couldn't find anything on the Blender API / it exceeds my understanding of the matter.

Here is my full code for reference:

````
###### MATCH LOCATION, ROTATION & SCALE ######

# check the difference in location between ref_obj and A
offset_location_selected_to_linked = A.location - ref_obj.location

# Calculate the rotation difference matrix between A and ref_obj for later use
rotation_difference_matrix = A.rotation_euler.to_matrix() @ ref_obj.rotation_euler.to_matrix().inverted()
# Match the rotation of A to ref_obj so B can be correctly positioned and be rotated with A later
A.rotation_euler = ref_obj.rotation_euler

# Position B with the offset_location_selected_to_linked
B.location += offset_location_selected_to_linked

# Handle rotation using context:
# 1. Deselect all objects
#bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
# 2. Select B
B.select_set(True)
# 3. Select A
A.select_set(True)
# 4. Set A to be the active obj
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = A

# Convert rotation matrix to Euler angles
rotation_difference_euler = rotation_difference_matrix.to_euler('XYZ')

# Convert radians to degrees
rotation_degrees = [math.degrees(angle) for angle in rotation_difference_euler]

# Set the pivot point for rotation to be the origin of A
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center='BOUNDS')

# Get the pivot location
pivot_location = A.location

# Calculate the rotation matrix for each axis
rotation_matrix = Euler(rotation_difference_euler, 'XYZ').to_matrix()

# get the rotation angle for x, y, and z
rotation_angle_x = rotation_matrix.to_euler('XYZ').x
rotation_angle_y = rotation_matrix.to_euler('XYZ').y
rotation_angle_z = rotation_matrix.to_euler('XYZ').z

# Calculate the scaling matrix for each axis
#scaling_matrix = Matrix(((scale_factor_x, 0, 0, 0), (0, scale_factor_y, 0, 0), (0, 0, scale_factor_z, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)))

# Rotate & scale both objects around the pivot point of A
for obj in [A, B]:
    M = (
        Matrix.Translation(pivot_location) @
        Matrix.Diagonal((scale_factor_x, scale_factor_y, scale_factor_z)).to_4x4() @
        Matrix.Rotation(rotation_angle_x, 4, (1, 0, 0)) @      
        Matrix.Translation(-pivot_location)
        )
    obj.matrix_world = M @ obj.matrix_world
        
# Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```
````